# How to require a frozen ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a small Ruby project and within a class I require a gem.
Now since the project has to be portable I have decided to freeze the gem so I have unpacked it.
My project now looks like

```
/
  /lib
    xml_generator.rb
  /vendor
    /gems
      /dbf-1.7.3
```

How can I specify within xml_generator to use dbf-1.7.3 located locally at vendor/gems/dbf-1.7.3?

I tried several solutions, the last one is

gem "dbf", :path => "../vendor/gems/dbf-1.7.3"
require 'dbf'

but it seems it is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to specify the exact version if dbf is installed on your system:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'dbf', '= 1.7.3'
```

If not you can try to require all the Ruby files under dbf-1.7.3:

```
Dir['./../vendor/gems/dbf-1.7.3/*.rb'].each{ |f| require f }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.
If I run xml_generator in a system where it is installed only dbf-1.5.2 

I get the following error:

RubyGem version error: dbf(1.5.2 not = 1.7.3)

Your solution works only if I have both (1.5.2 and 7.1.3) installed.

Thanks

Comment: I've revised my answer. Maybe you can use the 2nd option?

Comment: Not sure if your second option works but I'm pretty sure there is a better solution to solve it.
Thanks anyway for your help. I appreciate it.